# Do you need to build after editing javascript files?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have an ASP.NET project that I run via IIS locally.

When I change my .cs files I have to build to see the changes when I access my website via browser.

Do I have to build when I change my .js files?

Please justify your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to build your project after a change in a javascript file because javascript files don't require compilation.
Just pressing <kbd>ctrl+F5</kbd> (to clear your browsers cache) in the browser is sufficient to view your changes.